# Get part of XML-value in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have XML like:

```
<RES>
 <MUL>
  <SIN>
   <KEY name="a">
    <VALUE>a1</VALUE>
   </KEY>
   <KEY name="b">
    <VALUE>b1</VALUE>
   </KEY>
   <KEY name="c">
    <VALUE>c1</VALUE>
   </KEY>
   <KEY name="need">
    <MUL>
     <SIN>
      <KEY name="needID">
       <VALUE>ID</VALUE>
      </KEY>
      <KEY name="needOther">
       <VALUE>other</VALUE>
      </KEY>
      <KEY name="needOther2">
       <VALUE>other2</VALUE>
      </KEY>
     </SIN>
    </MUL>
   </KEY>
  </SIN>
 </MUL>
</RES>
```

My question is how to get value 'id' from the node with the name of `needID` ?

I tried with

```
XmlDocument xx = new XmlDocument();
xx.Load(MYDOC);

XmlNodeList node = xx.SelectNodes("/RES/MUL/SIN/KEY[@name='need']");
```

but after that I can't pick needID with

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(node);
var cource = from x in doc.Descendants("KEY")
select new { ID = doc.Element("VALUE").Value };
```

Please, help me!

Thanks! :)

Comment: I'd Consider use XElement and Descendants()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
// you're expecting only a single node - right?? So use .SelectSingleNode!
XmlNode node = xx.SelectSingleNode("/RES/MUL/SIN/KEY[@name='need']");

// if we found the node...
if(node != null)
{
    // get "subnode" inside that node
    XmlNode valueNode = node.SelectSingleNode("MUL/SIN/KEY[@name='needID']/VALUE");

    // if we found the <MUL>/<SIN>/<KEY name='needID'>/<VALUE> subnode....
    if(valueNode != null)
    {
        // get the inner text = the text of the XML element...
        string value = valueNode.InnerText;
    }
}
```

or you could even combine that into a single XPath operation, assuming you know that you have at most one single matching node in your XML document:

```
// define XPath
string xpath = "/RES/MUL/SIN/KEY[@name='need']/MUL/SIN/KEY[@name='needID']/VALUE";

// you're expecting only a single node - right?? So use .SelectSingleNode!
XmlNode node = xx.SelectSingleNode(xpath);

// if we found the node...
if(node != null)
{
    // get the inner text = the text of the XML element...
    string value = node.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll tried your first solution and it's work for me!

Answer (score 2):

How about something like below

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("url");

var cource = from x in doc.Descendants("KEY")
                 where x.Attribute("name").Value == "needID" 
                 select new { ID = x.Element("VALUE").Value };
```

Thanks

Deepu

Comment: Here I receive exception:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."...

Comment: The above code one I pasted was working one. I am not sure why its not working for you. If you change the URL to your XML file path.. It should work. or if you have this as string XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(MYDOC)

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

xml.Load(File.OpenRead(@"Your XML File"));

//XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/RES/MUL/SIN/KEY");

//You can use something like the below if the XML file is large and you need to read in more than one
//foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
//{
//Have a seperate class to store the values
//class class = new class();
//class.ID = xn.SelectSingleNode("./@needID").Value;
//
//}
```